# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server

Tags: java, mysql, sql, tomcat, syntax

I am having trouble with a java file when trying to run it on tomcat. I am suppose to be able to edit records that I put in a database, when I edit the records they do nothing. When I try to edit the records Tomcat throws me this error

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE cus_id =
>   '13'' at line 1

I figure this is the code that has the error because it has all of the SQL commands. The delete function works. I just can not edit a record...

Thanks for the help!

```
package crud.data;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import crud.business.Customer;

public class CustomerDB
{
 //insert method (pass customer object to parameter customer)
 public static int insert(Customer customer)
{
ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = null;
//comment
String query
  = "INSERT INTO customer (cus_fname, cus_lname, cus_street, cus_city, 
   cus_state, cus_zip, cus_phone, cus_email, cus_balance, cus_total_sales, 
   cus_notes) "
    + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
try {
  ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
  ps.setString(1, customer.getFname());
  ps.setString(2, customer.getLname());
  ps.setString(3, customer.getStreet());
  ps.setString(4, customer.getCity());
  ps.setString(5, customer.getState());
  ps.setString(6, customer.getZip());
  ps.setString(7, customer.getPhone());
  ps.setString(8, customer.getEmail());
  ps.setString(9, customer.getBalance());
  ps.setString(10, customer.getTotalSales());
  ps.setString(11, customer.getNotes());

  return ps.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e){
  System.out.println(e);
  return 0;
} finally {
  DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
  pool.freeConnection(connection);
    }
  }

 //update method
 public static int update(Customer customer)
 {
  ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
  Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
  PreparedStatement ps = null;

String query = "UPDATE customer SET "
    + "cus_fname = ?, "
    + "cus_lname = ?, "
    + "cus_street = ?, "
    + "cus_city = ?, "
    + "cus_state = ?, "
    + "cus_zip = ?, "
    + "cus_phone = ?, "
    + "cus_email = ?, "
    + "cus_balance = ?, "
    + "cus_total_sales = ?, "
    + "cus_notes = ?, "
    + "WHERE cus_id = ?";
try {
  ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
  ps.setString(1, customer.getFname());
  ps.setString(2, customer.getLname());
  ps.setString(3, customer.getStreet());
  ps.setString(4, customer.getCity());
  ps.setString(5, customer.getState());
  ps.setString(6, customer.getZip());
  ps.setString(7, customer.getPhone());
  ps.setString(8, customer.getEmail());
  ps.setString(9, customer.getBalance());
  ps.setString(10, customer.getTotalSales());
  ps.setString(11, customer.getNotes());
  ps.setString(12, customer.getId());

  return ps.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
  System.out.println(e);
  return 0;
} finally {
  DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
  pool.freeConnection(connection);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: you have way too much code here

Comment: Typo in UPDATE query: `+ "cus_notes = ?, "` (extra comma before `WHERE`).

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma `,` on the last value

```
+ "cus_notes = ?, "
```

so replace with

```
+ "cus_notes = ? "
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 64 : remove the comma from `+ "cus_notes = ?, "`.

Answer (score 0):

It is syntax error as shown in your console log.

> You have comma at the end of last value,remove it and give a try

`"cus_notes = ?"`

Answer (score -4):

You should post more full of errors, it is easier to identify where mistakes, now according to your tip is SQL syntax errors.